# Getting the DisplayMemberPath value of combobox in Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, c#-4.0, combobox

I have a silverlight app that populates a combobox from a sharepoint list.

here's the assignment of the combobox and I was able to bind to the combobox using an INotifyProperty. I am stuck on how to go about getting the value of the Display Member of the combobox.

```
<ComboBox Name="cboAwardType" SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedAwardType, Mode=TwoWay}"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding}" DataContext="{Binding}" />
```

code behind

```
  void _hrwebservice_GetAwardTypesCompleted(object sender, GetAwardTypesCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        List<AwardType> awardTypes = (List<AwardType>)e.Result.ToList();
        cboAwardType.ItemsSource = awardTypes;
        cboAwardType.DisplayMemberPath = "AType";
        cboAwardType.SelectedValuePath = "ID";           
    }
```

I can see the value in the SelectedItem. How do i access that AType value?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe...

```
var selectedType = ((AwardType) cboAwardType.SelectedItem).AType;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  string selectedType = cboAwardType.Text;
```